# How do I make conditions dependent to each other?

Tags: php, html, if-statement

This is my code:

```
$user_rep = $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ? $_SESSION['user_rep'] : null;
$html  = '<div class="privileges-cases">';
$html .= '<span class="' . <?= !is_null($user_rep) && $user_rep >= 1   ? "half-opacity" : ""; ?> . '"></spam><i class="fa fa-check"></i>At least 1 reputation for asking/answring question</span>';
$html .= '<span class="' . <?= !is_null($user_rep) && $user_rep >= 15  ? "half-opacity" : ""; ?> . '"></spam><i class="fa fa-check"></i>At least 15 reputation for upvote</span>';
$html .= '<span class="' . <?= !is_null($user_rep) && $user_rep >= 50  ? "half-opacity" : ""; ?> . '"></spam><i class="fa fa-check"></i>At least 50 reputation for commenting</span>';
$html .= '<span class="' . <?= !is_null($user_rep) && $user_rep >= 125 ? "half-opacity" : ""; ?> . '"></spam><i class="fa fa-check"></i>At least 125 reputation for downvote</span>';     
$html .= '</div>';
```

As you can see it's a list of all user privileges and I'm trying to make pale the ones that current user cannot access them. *(Noted that I don't want to do that if the user isn't logged in)*

My code works as well but it bothers me kinda, it is not sexy. I've written `!is_null($user_rep)` several times *(which seems dirty)* and some other conditions which would be better to be dependent , because if the first one is true, then no need to others even be checked.

Anyway, how can I do that? I mean how can I make it more clean?

Comment: You could default user rep to `0` rather than `null` then get rid of the `!is_null()` completely...

Comment: @naththedeveloper Oh neat .. thx

Comment: @naththedeveloper if 0 is not a valid rep

Comment: @MartinAJ  so if user reputation is less than 1 then you want to show all messages or only one message?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Always all messages should be shown. Just if the user is logged in, then I want to add a class named `half-opacity` *(which makes the element low-opacity)* to the ones that are bigger that current-user-reputation.

Comment: so based on reputation corresponding message will a bit hide (based on `half-opacity`)?

Comment: that's right @AlivetoDie

Comment: @AlivetoDie Like [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). though I think all messages are shown fully-opacity for you, since you have rep more than the max . Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jGV6.png) for me

Comment: I would store these in a DB table somewhere, and then generate it based on those.  But that is me.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix DB ? `:-)` Do you think is it worthy to make a table for 5 rows which never grow? I believe those numbers should be stored into a configuration file.

Comment: How often are you typing in those 5 values?  Actually, I would make a class and  make them class constants, but I would probably make them bitwise too. That way you could have 1 & 3 and not 2 but Its your stuff so I dont know the details.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix how often .. emm .. never `:-)`. And how exactly you mean by "bitwise"?

Comment: If you want to make it like StackOverflow you actually lower the opacity when the permission is granted, not the other way around. Also, there is no need to do `!is_null` because `null` will be type cast to `0` when comparing against an integer. Finally, IMO using ternary operator is inappropriate here since you're not echoing anything if the condition is not met. Just do `<?php if ($user_rep > $n) echo "half-opacity"; ?>`

Comment: @MartinAJ  the link you have shown to be based on that you are trying to do exactly opposite of it. Like if a user has 0 rep. then all messages will have ``half-opacity` (means hide), which is actually not correct. Don't you think so?

Comment: @AlivetoDie You are right .. I want something exactly opposite. My bad. I've edited my question.

Comment: @Mike Good point about type casting and ternary operator. Thank you.

Comment: This is a poor explanation bitwise [wikkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)  I wrote a better one the other day but I answer so many questions I cant find it ... lol  Anyway My point is this approach is not SOLID

Answer (score 0):

You could just set to 0 instead of null.

```
$user_rep = $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ? $_SESSION['user_rep'] : 0;
$html  = '<div class="privileges-cases">';
$html .= '<span class="' . <?= $user_rep >= 1   ? "half-opacity" : ""; ?> . '"></spam><i class="fa fa-check"></i>At least 1 reputation for asking/answring question</span>';
$html .= '<span class="' . <?= $user_rep >= 15  ? "half-opacity" : ""; ?> . '"></spam><i class="fa fa-check"></i>At least 15 reputation for upvote</span>';
$html .= '<span class="' . <?= $user_rep >= 50  ? "half-opacity" : ""; ?> . '"></spam><i class="fa fa-check"></i>At least 50 reputation for commenting</span>';
$html .= '<span class="' . <?= $user_rep >= 125 ? "half-opacity" : ""; ?> . '"></spam><i class="fa fa-check"></i>At least 125 reputation for downvote</span>';     
$html .= '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the core of what you're trying to do, I would create an associative array of privileges and the reputation required for them, and loop through that, setting or omitting the half opacity class. Here's a working example, note I set the "users" rep to 16:

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d82323cef2256617982efd306ff85bfcf6128095)</kbd>

```
$user_rep = $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ? $_SESSION['user_rep'] : null;

$privileges = array(
    'Asking/Answering Questions' => 1,
    'Upvote' => 15,
    'Comment' => 50,
    'Downvote' => 125
);

echo '<div class="privileges-cases">';
    foreach( $privileges as $privilege => $rep){
        if( $user_rep == null ){
            $class = 'half-opacity';
        } else {
            $class = $user_rep >= $rep ? '' : 'half-opacity';
        }

        echo "<span class=\"$class\"></span><i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>At least $rep reputation for $privilege</span>";
    }
echo '</div>';
```

You could make it even more succinct by moving the value comparison with the null comparison. Either way it does make the most sense with how you've got it laid out right now to just compare with the reputation required.

Something like this is about as "clean" as I can think to make the code you've got.

```
$user_rep = $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ? $_SESSION['user_rep'] : null;

$privileges = array(
    1   => 'Asking/Answering Questions',
    15  => 'Upvote',
    50  => 'Comment',
    125 => 'Downvote'
);

echo '<div class="privileges-cases">';
    foreach( $privileges as $rep => $privilege ){
        $class = $user_rep < $rep ? 'half-opacity' : '';
        echo "<span class='$class'></span><i class='fa fa-check'></i>At least $rep reputation for $privilege</span>";
    }
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `@` http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Everywhere whenever you are performing a check

`<?= @$user_rep >= 1   ? "half-opacity" : ""; ?>`

@ operator will ignore the error, i.e. undefined variable error

**IMPORTANT** `@` operator will only disable error for the current line for code. It doesn't hide any other errors generated by your php script.